# Doctrine: Change date format when getting and setting field values

Tags: php, doctrine

I want to be able to **get** and **set** the date using my own date format (*dd/mm/yyyy*) and not doctrine (*yyyy-mm-dd*). I've found a way that is specifying a *getter* and *setter* for **every date field** however I want do it in a more convenient way (*1 setter + 1 getter for every date field in every table is a lot*)

```
class Curs extends BaseCurs {
    private function fechaDesdeEsp($fecha){
        $fecha = new DateTime($fecha);
        return $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    private function fechaDesdeIso($fecha){
        $fecha = new DateTime($fecha);
        return $fecha->format('d/m/Y');
    }
    public function setFechainici($fecha_inici) {
        return $this->_set('fecha_inici', $this->fechaDesdeEsp($fecha_inici));
    }
    public function getFechainici() {
        return $this->fechaDesdeIso($this->_get('fecha_inici'));
    }

}
```

Hope you find a solution, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found this to be the best solution for me:

```
/// models/DateFormatBehaior.php
class DateFormatListener extends Doctrine_Record_Listener{

    public function preInsert(Doctrine_event $Event){
        $this->_prepare_date($Event);
    }

    public function preUpdate(Doctrine_event $Event){
        $this->_prepare_date($Event);
    }

    // Private stuff
    private function _prepare_date(Doctrine_event $Event){
        $Model = $Event->getInvoker();
        foreach($Model->getTable()->getColumns() as $FieldName=>$Field){
            if($Field['type']=='timestamp'){
                if(preg_match("/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})/",$Model[$FieldName],$Matches)){
                    $Model->$FieldName = sprintf("%s-%s-%s 00:00:00",$Matches[3],$Matches[2],$Matches[1]); // YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
class DateFormatTemplate extends Doctrine_Template{

    public function setTableDefinition(){

        $this->addListener(new DateFormatListener);
    }

}
```

Then, each model who has timestamp fields:

```
/// models/MyModel.php
abstract class MyModel extends Doctrine_Record{

    public function setTableDefinition(){
        // [...]
    }
     public function setUp(){
        parent::setUp();
        $this->actAs("DateFormatTemplate");
        // [...]
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try overriding `__call`, which handles Doctrine's automatic get/set stuff, and maybe `__get` and `__set` too. Then, in those functions, look at the table's metadata (you should be able to get to this via `getTable()` and a method on the table class). The metadata contains the type of the column, so just test whether this is of the type you want or not.

This way you can just have the overrides for the magic methods and they should handle it for you. I recall you could also put this in a custom class which inherits from Doctrine_Record, and then modify Doctrine's model generator settings so that it uses your custom record class as the base.

Look at Doctrine's API documentation (or their source code, it's pretty clean) to find out the specifics I forgot :)