# Using "d-m-Y H:i:s" dates with Doctrine?

Tags: php, oracle, doctrine-orm

I'm using Oracle as my RDBMS and I store dates and timestamps using the Spanish format `(NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF")`.

The problem is, I'm using Doctrine as ORM and it can't convert the database values to its datetime type, as it expects the `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` format. Is there a way to indicate the format I'm using to Doctrine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end I extended the Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType type and overwrote the convertToDatabaseValue and convertToPHPValue methods

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/it/function.date-create-from-format.php) in this way

```
date_create_from_format("Y-m-d", $the_data_you_need_to_convert);
```

though this function is available on php >=5.3.0 versions

Comment: I think you missunderstood Gianps. The problem is retrieving the data and converting it from the Spanish format to the English one (and I don't have control in this process because is done by Doctrine), not saving it

Comment: ok, are you searching something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216586/doctrine-change-date-format-when-getting-and-setting-field-values